# styling a horizontal dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigation

I made a horizontal dropdown menu for my website and I have 2 questions about styling:
1. How can I add a small blue triangle on top of the header border which would be shown on hover,like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAjyS.png 
2. I've added a small arrow to the right of the links in the main nav.I did this by specifying a css class for each of the list elements with a dropdown menu in wordpress,and then I used a css :after pseudo element to add a font icon to the right of those elements,the problem with that is that it also adds the icon to the dropdown menu links and I don't want that.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPxAK.png -wordpress menu structure

html:

```
 <header>
    <div id="wrap">     
        <a id="logo" href="<?php bloginfo('siteurl');?>" title="Vratite se  na početnu stranicu" >
            <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/logo.png" alt="Obrtnička Škola Koprivnica Logo" width="53" height="70" />
        </a>
        <h1>OBRTNIČKA ŠKOLA KOPRIVNICA</h1>
        <nav class="cf">
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Main' , 'container' => none)); ?>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
<div id="subnav"></div>
```

css:

```
/*****NAV STYLES*******/
nav{
    position:absolute;
    top: 42px;
    padding-bottom:2.7em;
}

nav li {
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
nav li a {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
    color: white;
}

nav ul li:first-child {
    padding-left: 70px;
}

nav ul ul{
    position: absolute;
    left: -999em;
    bottom: 0em;
    min-width: 230%;
    max-width: 170%;
}

nav ul ul li{
    font-size: 0.75em;
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
nav ul ul li:first-child {
    padding-left: 0;
}
nav ul ul li a {
    color: #4F4F4F;
}

nav ul ul li a:hover {
    color: black;
}


.dropdown a:after {
    content: "s";
    font-family: 'Guifxv2TransportsRegular';
    color: white;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    padding: 0 0 2px 3px;
}

/* make sub-menu appear on active links only */
nav li.active > ul {
    left:0;
}

/* clearfix micro hack = http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/ */
/* For modern browsers */
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}

.cf:after {
    clear:both;
}

/* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
.cf {
    zoom:1;
}
```

javascript:

```
        // on mouse over, remove all active classes from main menu items and add active class to current item
        $('nav > ul > li > a').mouseover(function() {
        // remove all active classes
        $('nav > ul > li').removeClass('active');
        // add active class to current item
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        });
```

Comment: Are you sure people will have this font-type installed to see the arrow character? : 'Guifxv2TransportsRegular' ? About positioning a blue arrow, I'd create a small image representing the blue arrow, and set it as a background image for the `<li>` element that will be applied on `:hover`. To make sure the image is properly positioned at the bottom and center of the `<li>` element - I'd use: `background:url(plava-strelica.png) no-repeat center bottom;`.

Comment: @font-face is supported in modern browsers,besides,I could have just as easily used an image.                                              I used an image as a background for links in the main nav and it works great,thanks! I still need help with question 2, though.

Comment: njeh, I removed my comment cause the second LI had not more UL inside, but the arrow still appeared. I suggest to use Javascript. If you want I can show you how to do it!

Comment: That's weird because I used this code: `nav > ul > li.dropdown > a:after {
    content: url(images/strelica-dropdown.png)
}` and it works fine.

Comment: That's great! Say hello to Koprivnica if you go that way ;)!

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress adds the .current-menu-item and .current_page_item class to the menu if you have that called correctly:

i.e.

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Main Menu' )); ?>
```

Simply style your `.current_page_item` with a background using absolute positioning. Something like:

```
.current_page_item {
    background: url(arrow.png) no repeat;
    position: absolute:
    top: -25px // Adjust this to see it depending on your padding, margins
    left: 50%; // Again, play with this percentage or use pixels
}
```